# Angularjs Dynamic Controller with Dynamic Parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have use requirejs, angularamd and ui.bootstrap in my project. In case of popup form I have $uibModal from ui.bootstrap. But I cannot pass a parameter "items" from resolve. How can I inject parameters for controller which have resolved dynamically?

```
function open(size, parentSelector) {
        var parentElem = parentSelector ?
          angular.element($document[0].querySelector('.grid ' + parentSelector)) : undefined;

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
            animation: vm.animationsEnabled,
            ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
            ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
            size: size,
            appendTo: parentElem,
            templateUrl: 'Views/Shared/ColSetting.html',
            resolve: {
                load: ['$q','$rootScope',function ($q, $rootScope) {
                    var loadController = "Views/Shared/ColSettingController";
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    require([loadController], function () {
                        deferred.resolve(items);
                        $rootScope.$apply();
                    });
                    return deferred.promise;
                }]
            }
        });
```

This is controller I want to call.

```
'use strict';

define(['application-configuration', 'ajaxService'], function (app) {
function ColSettingController(items) {
    var vm = this;

    //vm.content = $rootScope.content;

    vm.ok = function () {
        //$uibModalInstance.close(vm.selected.item);
    };

    vm.cancel = function () {
        //$uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}

app.register.controller("ColSettingController", ColSettingController);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `ui.bootstrap`, `resolve` property is a map object. The map object contains key/value pairs of:

- **key** – `{string}`: a name of a dependency to be injected into the controller.
- **factory** - `{string|function}`:
  If `string`, then it is an alias for a service.
  Otherwise if `function`, then it is injected and the return value is treated as the dependency. If the result is a promise, it is resolved before the controller is instantiated and its value is injected into the controller.

In your case, you are using `load`, but your controller expect `items` to be injected, I assume it fails saying it can't find `items`, right? It is because what you are injecting is `load`.

You need to change the name of your property in the `resolve`, `load` for `items`.

```
resolve: {
    //change 'load' for 'items' here
    items: [....rest of your code goes here....]
```

Also, it is recommended to use the property `$inject` before declaring controllers/components and others, something like this:

```
function ColSettingController(items) {
    //some code here
}

ColSettingController.$inject = ['items'];

app.register.controller("ColSettingController", ColSettingController);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thank a lot. Now I got it. :-)

Comment: @AungThanOo if the answer was helpful or guided you to solve your issue, considering voting +1 or accepting it.